# Minimum number of blocked squares to ensure a draw in a generically sized tic-tac-toe grid

Tags: numerical-methods, algorithms, tic-tac-toe

There is a Japanese puzzle called marupeke which involves an $x$ by $y$ sized grid, where the objective is to place a  $O$ or $X$ on every square so that there is not a "chain" of length 3.

Some tiles in the grid may be blocked out beforehand where a $O$ or $X$ can not be placed.

Here is an example of a solved grid:

[image: From http://www.crauswords.com/marupeke.html]

My question is if there is a way to determine the minimum number of blocked squares needed to solve an $x$ by $y$ grid without brute forcing every solution, or at least a way of generating solvable grids for any size in a short amount of time.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can always fill any $x \times y$ grid with `X`'s and `O`'s without having 3 in a row. Extend the following pattern to fill the grid:

```
XXOOXXOOXXOOXXOO...
OOXXOOXXOOXXOOXX...
XXOOXXOOXXOOXXOO...
OOXXOOXXOOXXOOXX...
XXOOXXOOXXOOXXOO...
OOXXOOXXOOXXOOXX...
...
```

That's a repeated tiling of the $2 \times 4$ pattern:

```
XXOO
OOXX
```

So we see that any marupeke puzzle is solvable when we shade some blocked squares, but before we write down any `X`'s and `O`'s. Usually you get some of those pre-filled for you, with the aim of creating a puzzle with a *unique* solution: that's the hard part.

For a (non-algorithmic) guide to the hard part, see [this Puzzling StackExchange post](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/61376/how-does-one-go-about-creating-a-new-grid-deduction-puzzle).